# Chrome: JSON (or other object) into chrome_debug.log

Tags: google-chrome

when I use chrome.exe with  --enable-logging parameter it enables chrome to log console messages into debug file.
Sadly it missing the object details:

Example:
`[1208:1164:1028/12048.086:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "%c[WS Message] something color: #7c7c7c", source:something.js (1)`

The (1) Stands for the JSON object inside I want to explore in real time in Python. Anyone have idea how to make chrome to save object as string for example in chrome_debug.log?? (Extension or some console command?)
Or any other solution that would enable to view the object in realtime in python?

(Yes i know you can right click on in actual chrome console by mouse then use "copy object", So yes, technicaly, i can make a macro which would do it in real time, but that woud be completely crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by making Chome extension in Java, that copy-paste JSON objects from dev console. Little bit workaround, but better working that Selenium.